# Which key does this showkey command belong to?

Tags: linux, command-line, keyboard

I think I have a faulty keyboard which randomly pressing some key. So I pressed `showkey -a` to see which key is being pressed. I got the below result.
[image: result]
I feel its the `END` key as i tried a visual tool as well. But the result shows 3 lines so I'm confused what it means? And there are two `END`key in my keyboard as well. Does it actually belong to END key press?

Comment: Pictures of text are less useful than text: They are hard to read, and near impossible to read by blind people. Go to the effort to transcribe the 3 times (that keep repeating), so that we can more easily answer you question.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627925/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-keyboard-keycodes

Comment: The `-a` flag just obfuscates the output. If you remove it, you will get the decimal keycodes, which you can easily look up in `dumpkeys` output.